# Importerror no module named vtk

Tags: python, windows, vtk, importerror

I'm trying to run a Python.py file with:

import vtk

but, I get the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CYLINDER.py", line 6, in 
     import vtk
ImportError: No module named vtk

Steps I've taken:

- Compiled VTK 7 following these instructions: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Building/Windows#Step_7_-_Manual_building (no failures)
- Changed PYTHONPATH variables: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Tutorials/PythonEnvironmentSetup

Currently running Python 2.7.11 32-bit, compiled using CMake and Visual Studio 2010, and using cygwin for windows

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What did you choose as your VTK installation directory?

Comment: after I compiled in Visual Studio? I created a folder in C:/VTK

Comment: What are the contents of that directory?  Specifically, where is the `vtk` subdirectory located?

Comment: if you're talking about the site-packages, the vtk_xx_.pyd files are all correctly generated.

Comment: Can you start a Python prompt form the vtk directory and import vtk?

Comment: I'm asking for the directory location of `vtk`, so I can compare that to your PYTHONPATH setting.

Comment: Hi Wayne, I have no idea what starting a python prompt from the VTK directory and importing means.  does that mean navigating to vtk directory in command line and typing "import vtk" ?

Comment: Hi John,

**VTK** location is: C:\Program Files (x86)\VTK

**PYTHONPATH** =
c:\python27\Lib\site-packages;
c:\python27\DLLs;
c:\python27\Lib;
c:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\lib\python2.7\site-packages\vtk

Comment: I tried running the .py file using command line and I get a **different** error: loadTree (sys.argv[1], Nodes, Edges ) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: In order to import a package, the package's parent directory must be in `PYTHONPATH`.  So, since vtk appears to be installed in `c:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\lib\python2.7\site-packages\vtk`, that means `c:\Program Files (x86)\VTK\lib\python2.7\site-packages` should be in your `PYTHONPATH`, which it does not appear to be.

Comment: @John, I tried your suggestion and also returned the import error: no module named vtk.